# How to add icon when last reading date is more than 24hours old?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

so in my html I have this:

```
{{hsParametersLastRead.readingDate | date:'medium'}}
```

and I have this in the controller:

```
$http.get(hsParametersLastReadEndpoint).success(function (hsParametersLastRead) {
                $scope.hsParametersLastRead = hsParametersLastRead;
                console.log(moment());
            });
```

I have this moment thing that I don't really know how to use.

What I want: to be able to make an icon visible if the hsParametersLastRead.readingDate is older than 24 hours. Can I somehow compare it with the 'moment' object and check if 24 hours has passed since?

Comment: moment provides helpers like this one: moment().subtract(1, 'days'), that'll give you your 24hr window. Then you need to compare the times. Can you create a plunker pls.

Comment: I don't know how and what to add to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
var now = moment();
var difference = moment($scope.hsParametersLastRead.readingDate).diff(now, 'hours');
```

Difference should be the number of hours between now and your hsParametersLastRead property.

Comment: i try to test it. Console.log(now); returns it correctly, but Console.log(difference); doesn't

Comment: apparenlty it worked with var difference = (moment($scope.hsParametersLastRead).add(2, 'hours')).isBefore(moment());
                console.log(difference);

Comment: can you do console.log($scope.hsParametersLastRead)

Comment: yes. found the problem, had to do (moment($scope.hsParametersLastRead.readingDate).add(24, 'hours')).isBefore(moment());, i was doing it to the whole json file! now to figure out to make an icon appear when true